# How did A.M.A.Z.O. manage to copy Kryptonian powers?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse

During the "Elseworlds" crossover for the CW shows *Arrow*, *Flash* and *Supergirl* the android A.M.A.Z.O. is activated.  Cisco and Caitlin determine that the robot was built to track (and copy) metahuman powers.

But Superman and Supergirl get copied as well.  Their powers are not meta in nature at all, are not the result of the dark matter etc - they're a fact of their alien biology interacting with a yellow sun.

So how exactly does A.M.A.Z.O. manage to copy those?  To be clear, I'm looking for explanations from anyone related to the shows who may have been asked about it, or if an in-universe explanation exists, I'll accept that as well.

Comment: Not an answer, but: in the comics, Amazo was built to copy the powers of the Justice League. That would have included (at the time) Flash, Superman, Wonder Woman, Green Lantern, Aquaman, and the Martian Manhunter. So, aliens, people with powers granted by accident, people with external power sources, people with in-born powers, and one character whose powers have a connection to the Greek gods.

Comment: @RDFozz I know the history from the comics but I don't see how it can apply here as Earth-1 (in the CW DC universe) doesn't have ANY kryptonians (or at least, none we've ever met yet) and it was stated on the show that Amazo was designed to work on metas - which Kara and Clark are not...

Comment: ... making them an unknown. It could be as simple as the mechanisms behind alien powers being similar enough to metas that it happens to work on both. Or, that the show creators just wanted him to work the same as in the comics. It is fundamentally "magical technology". Just wanted to note that the comics never worried about how the android could copy all of those powers.

Answer (score 1):

There can be two explanation for it:

1. Caitlin used the term loosely this time. Like in comics metahuman term is not limited to meta created by single method but used for anyone with powers.
2. Kryptonian powers are also meta in nature and work similarly so can be copied by the same method.

Also all the version of A.M.A.Z.O. I have seen adopted before had no issue to copy the power of any superbeing (alien or human).

Also, Killer Frost power is not like any other dark-matter powered Meta humans and still A.M.A.Z.O.easily copied it.